# How to permanently remove new volume in the dock

Tags: dock

I use Ubuntu 20.04,
and I want to remove the new volume icon
How can I permanently remove the new volume icon from the dock?

[image: Dock with "new volume" icon]

thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1355501/edit) your question and add more details like the version of Ubuntu that you are using.  Also, please add details of what causes that new volume to show up.  Do you want to remove that icon?  Or do you want the icon to work if you add a new hard drive?  Any more details will really help us help you!  Thank you!

Comment: ok I use Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to remove icon @Terrance and yeah I get that icon all the time

Comment: Try right-clicking the icon and choosing Remove from Favorites.

Comment: @Terrance I actually do not get 'Remove from favorites'. I get 'New Window' and 'Unmount'

Comment: One more place you can try. Right click on the icon on the far right and choose Dash to Dock settings. Then go to the Launchers tab and turn off the `Show Mounted Volumes`. Other than that, I am running out of ideas.

Comment: @Terrance Thankyou I got answer for this question